# Call method from inside Window from UserControl - WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, methods

I've got a second window with some UserControl inside UserControl. - I mean UserControl2 is inside UserControl1 which is in SecondWindow. I I want to call the method placed inside the second window by clicking a button inside UserControl2.
I've tried this:

```
    SecondWindow sWindow = new SecondWindow();
    sWindow.ChangeAppControl();
```

But nothing works and method is not called :( Any Ideas?

Thanks a lot
Antek

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Use routed commands.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 make sure your method is public:

```
    public void ChangeWindowApp()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The Method is called.");
    }
```

Step 2:

```
  foreach(Window SWindow in Application.Current.Windows)
  {
       if(SWindow is SecondWindow)
       {
           SecondWindow ParentWindow = (SecondWindow)SWindow;
           ParentWindow.ChangeWindowApp();
       }
  }
```

Comment: Yeah my method is public, but it's still not working. Message box is not shown.